# Highcharts pie with a single value in %

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I have several values in percent, that should be displayed with nested pies. Is it possible that each pie doesn't fill up to 100%? e.g. when a value is 0.5 it should only draw a half pie. I tried it with `yAxis: {max: 1.0}`, but this doesn't has any effect. I created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZL9YD/

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify an extra data point in your data to plot the remaing percentage as pies always add up to 100%:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Run1',
    data: [{name: "Run1", y: 0.6, color: "#ff0000"},{name: "", y: 0.4, color: "white"}],
},
{
    name: 'Run2',
    data: [{name: "Run2", y: 0.8},{name: "", y: 0.2, color: "white"}],
    innerSize: '80%'
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3MUE/

Comment: Hmmm, I also had that idea, but thought maybe there is a better way to do this. But thanks for the answer. If no other way is around, I'll try this